# Exported Next.js site: listeners not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I built a site with React.js and Next.js and now I'm trying to export it with `next build && next export` to then upload to Github pages.
When I run `npx serve` to test it locally, the site, loads, but navigation and custom event not working. They are working fine when I test the real app using `npm run dev`

**Update:**
I noticed that the problem is that my `onClick` listeners are not being fired at all.

For navigation I have this code:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: name })
    if (name === 'home') {
        Router.push("/")
    } else {
       Router.push(`/${name}`) 
    }
}
```

And for the event:

```
<input checked={this.state.theme === "dark"} onClick={this.sliderChanged} type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

My `next.config.js` contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
        '/': { page: '/'},
        '/about': { page: '/about'},
        '/blog': { page: '/blog'}
    }
},
}
```

Comment: Could you provide additional code for the components where you have your `onClick` actions? Do you get any errors in the console when navigating/clicking on stuff?